# Three MySQL queries for one operation!? I think not

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'll try to be right to the point. Here's what I'm trying to do.
I have two tables that I need to pull data from:

```
membershipstable = || groupid || templateid || userid
                   ||    2    ||      1     ||   0
                   ||    0    ||      1     ||   3
                   ||    2    ||      0     ||   4

userstable = || id || firstname || lastname || email
```

What I would like to do would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM userstable WHERE id = userid (in memberships table) -- AND/OR --  WHERE id = userid IF groupid is associated with templateid, and templateid is equal to $currenttemplateid
```

Or in human speak: Look at the `memberships` table and if you find a row containing a `templateid` that matches `$currenttemplateid` then bring back the `userid` from that row. Then, look at the `userstable` and retrieve the information for each user who has an `id` matching a `userid` we found above. Also, if you find any rows that contain a `templateid` that matches `$currenttemplateid`, then look at the `groupid` in that row and bring back any `userid` that is in any row with that `groupid`, and again retrieve the information for any user with an `id` that matches the `userid` that was found above.

I'm sorry if my explanation is somewhat confusing, and if my question reeks of newbishness (also, don't worry, I'm not using unprepared statements in the actual project)... I know that this can be done with MySQL in a single, efficient, and beautiful query but I'm at a complete loss as to what exactly that query would look like... Thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: To be clear, I have figured out how to use a join to pull the data from `userstable` by columns in the `membershipstable` - the bigger issue I'm having at the moment is the part of the query that would deal with the affiliation between the goupid, templateid, and userid part...

Comment: I am sure one of us can do this if you share the url to the sqlfiddle you create with data loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 3-way join to find all the users in the same group as the selected member.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM usertable AS u
JOIN membershiptable AS m1 ON u.id = m1.userid
JOIN membershiptable AS m2 ON m1.groupid = m2.groupid
WHERE m2.templateid = $currenttemplateid
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20d48/1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help sir. As for the query, if I only wanted to return a few of the columns from the `usertable` then I could simply substitute `SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname,` for the `SELECT u.*` portion of the query correct?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may come looking for the answer at a later time, there is the concern of ending up with duplicate entries in the return if a user has been assigned to both a template and a group that is also assigned to the template. A solution for this is to put `DISTINCT` directly after the `SELECT` portion of the query. E.g.

```
$query = "
        SELECT DISTINCT
            u.id,
            u.firstname,
            u.lastname,
            u.username,
            u.email
        FROM $userstable AS u
        INNER JOIN $membershipstable AS M1 ON u.id = M1.userid
        INNER JOIN $membershipstable AS M2 ON M1.groupid = M2.groupid
        WHERE M2.templateid = :currenttemplateid
    ";
```

This returns only non duplicate results.